# How can I assert the content of Flash messages in phpunit tests?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

Any idea on how i can test CakePHP  controller flash message content in phpunit testing? I need to test this:

```
if ($var == "yes") {
   //do something
} else {         
   $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again;));
}
```

Comment: I think you should test this through the UI using something like Selenium. Basically: 1) Perform the action that's supposed to trigger the flash message 2) Check for redirect 3) Check for flash message on page

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-flash-messages), if you are using version 3.4.7 or later, you can use the enableRetainFlashMessages() function before issuing your get/post/whatever. Then you can check for the existence of the flash message by using assertSession().

Example:

```
$this->enableRetainFlashMessages();
$this->get('call-your-public-controller-function-here');
$this->assertSession('Invalid username or password, try again', 'Flash.flash.0.message');
```

I stated "according to the documentation" because I'm actually using an older version right now (3.1.13) that does not include that method, so I have not personally tested the code above.

HOWEVER... I have found that, with the version I'm using, I can basically do the same thing without issuing the enableRetainFlashMessages() call. By using assertSession(), I can check for the existence of the expected message using the process described above. I had assumed that it would not work, but it did! (That never happens...)